# Get count posts of model Post Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a model Post, in this model I created accesor:

```
protected $appends = ['post_count']; 

public function getPostCountAttribute() {
   return $this->count();
}
```

When I want to show a `post_count` in blade:

```
$post->post_count;
```

I get error: `Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$post_count`

Why I get this error? And how I can fix it?

In controller:

```
public function allPosts() {
    $posts = Post::active()->paginate(15);
    return view('posts', compact('posts'));
}
```

In blade:

```
{{ $posts->post_count }}

@foreach($posts as $post)
    {{ $post->title }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Can you post your foreach loop?

Comment: @ManzurulHoqueRumi updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It feels like you want to display the count of Posts in your view. This is not a good case to use an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor). You would typically use an accessor to modify the attributes of a single Post.

Do this instead:

```
public function allPosts() 
{    
    $posts = Post::active()->paginate(15);

    return view('posts', compact('posts'));
}
```

... and then in your blade

```
{{ $posts->total() }}

@foreach($posts as $post)
    {{ $post->title }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: But can I optimize this ? Compact this in 1 query.. Because an extra query is received..

Comment: It seems from the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination#usage), you could just call `total()` on the paginator to receive the total number of items. See [this.](https://implode.io/SCu9mP)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong. `post_count` will only work in foreach loop for every model. To count all post you could do like this `$posts->count()`

[Count](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-count)